# Do the Blood Mage and Battlemage specializations work well together?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

The Battlemage has a spell that will take health from all nearby enemies and give it to the caster.  But it costs mana to keep it running.

The Blood Mage has one that will cause all spells to pull from health rather than mana.

Do these work together well?  Will it work to keep your health up if you have enough bad guys around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is: they can.

I ran a Blood Mage/Battle Mage my first play through and I found out very quickly that a Battle Mage is really designed for tanking where a Blood Mage is designed to not take damage. If you have someone else to do the Tanking, then this actually works well as you become a semi-durable dps.  If you're the tank, you quickly find out using heath as a resource is a bad idea.

Comment: being a tank using health as a resource might be fun if you're roll-playing a sadomasochist.